# Avoid to run Angular Controller twice/Ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to call a function inside a controller but it runs twice and, as you may know this is not viable, specially if you want to insert a record into a database because the data duplicates "itself".

Here you have the code I'm using

The Module, Factory and Controller I'm using is this (contained in `AdminController.js`):

```
var $biocompadmin = angular.module('BioCompAdminApp', ['ngGrid'], function($interpolateProvider) {
    // Se ha cambiado la nomenclatura de Angular {{}} para que no choque con la de Blade
    // en Laravel. Ahora se empleará <% %>.
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

$biocompadmin.factory('modifyHCSection', function($http, $q){
    return{
        executeCode: function(obj){
            //console.log("antes ...");
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var datos = [];
            item = {};
            item['search'] = obj;
            datos.push(item);
            datos = JSON.stringify(obj);

            $url = '../../hc_sections/' + obj.id;

            $http.put($url, {data:datos})
            .then(function(result) {
                 //resolve the promise as the data
                //console.log(result.data[1]['name']);
                console.log("Ejecucion A: " + result.data);

                deferred.resolve(result.data);
             });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});


$biocompadmin.controller("modHCSectionCtrl", function($scope,modifyHCSection,$window) {

    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.sendForm = function() {
         modifyHCSection.executeCode($scope.formData).then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data['success']){
                alert(data['message']);
                $window.location.href ="../../hc_sections";
            }else{
                alert(data['errors']['fallo']);
            }
            //$scope.message = data.message;
        });
    };
});
```

The HTML is:

```
<div ng-controller="modHCSectionCtrl" id="modHCSection">
<div class="panel panel-default" id="editHCSection" >
<div class="panel-heading" ><h3 class="panel-title">Modificando la Sección Pediatria</h3></div>

<div class="panel-body">
<form id="modHCSectionForm" name="modHCSectionForm" ng-submit="sendForm()"
>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="formData.id" ng-init="formData.id='11'" />
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" ng-model="formData.name" ng-init="formData.name='Pediatria'"
           data-bv-notempty="true"
           data-bv-notempty-message="El nombre de la sección es obligatorio y no puede estar vacío"

           data-bv-stringlength="true"
           data-bv-stringlength-max="100"
           data-bv-stringlength-message="La longitud del nombre debe ser menor de 100 caracteres"
        />
    </div>
    <br>

   <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Contacto</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" id="contact" placeholder="" ng-model="formData.contact" ng-init="formData.contact='Manuel Pena'"
            data-bv-notempty="true"
            data-bv-notempty-message="El nombre del contacto es obligatorio y no puede estar vacío"

            data-bv-regexp="true"
            data-bv-regexp-regexp="^[a-zA-Z\s]+$"
            data-bv-regexp-message="El nombre del contacto solo puede contener caracteres y espacios en blanco sencillos"

        />
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Telefono 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone1" id="phone1" placeholder="" ng-model="formData.phone1" ng-init="formData.phone1=''"
            />
    </div>      
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Telefono 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone2" id="phone2" placeholder="" ng-model="formData.phone2" ng-init="formData.phone2=''"
        />
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button id='modifyHCSection_Cancel' type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
            <button id='modifyHCSection_Save' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Approach 1: not repeat the controller call twice

I try it, I supose there is no double call in the HTML

Approach 2: take out the data function from the controller

As you can see I create a factory to separate the data from the controller and I'm using $q.defer to "defer" the answer and execute code after the asynchronous call ends.

So, I insist, maybe a newbie question but I really appreciate any help you can give me in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

$http.put($url, {data:datos}) you should not chain then function, it already returns a promise to controller to use

Comment: So, do you suggest to use .success immediately after the $http.put($url, {data:datos}) instead .then?. I tried it also, but it continues executing twice. Could you please give me an example of the implementation? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: OK, the are two ways in order to submit a form: using ng-submit into the form and an input type "submit"; and, in the other hand, using ng-click in the button. I've tried both and, this is strange, when using the ng-click method it works fine, it sends just one time the call to the controller, BUT if I use ng-submit method, it's sends two request to the controller. Dos this have any sense?

Comment: without the full code, it is hard to tell what is going on. For example, $window.location.href ="../../hc_sections"; does this call the same controller again?

Comment: Well ABOS, thanks for your support. In fact "../../hc_sections" is a Restful call that redirect the page to a page with a list of sections. Right now I'm using ng-click approach instead the ng-submit one. Just don't understand why using ng-submit the code runs twice. ng-click calls the same controller and function than the one used by ng-submit so I supose the error must be associated to the ng-submit events related or the interaction with the UI. (IMHO)